# How to use layout as selector resource

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to use layout as selector but there are an error on inflating view and app give 
ANR below

> org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2:
>   invalid drawable tag LinearLayout
>   at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:877)

Do you have any idea

Thank you

**drawable/selector_map_all.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:drawable="@layout/map_atm_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
      <item android:drawable="@layout/map_atm" />
</selector>
```

**layout/map_atm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout    
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aresource="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/List_color2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ico_info" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextViewNormalOpac"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Hepsi" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**layout/map_atm_selected.xml**

```
<? xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aresource="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/List_color2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ico_info" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextViewNormalOpac"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Hepsi" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is your selector called ico_info.xml? Have you tried cleaning project?

Comment: icoinfo is an png file, and i cleaned the project but nothing changed, thank you

Comment: So what is the name of your selector?

Comment: drawable/selector_map_all.xml

Comment: Why would you want a layout in a selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of your exception is because you cannot use `LinearLayout` in selector, because `StateListDrawable` class (which is in fact selector) can keep as a state only Drawable objects, but `LinearLayout` is not a Drawable. You can check for available Drawables (besides ordinary picture) inside `createFromXmlInner` method or [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html).